# Can't Login user using Axios in React Native

Tags: react-native, authentication, axios

I am new to React Native so bear with me. I am attempting to create a login for my app using Axios but keep running into the same error. Some of my code is listed below. I was able to run my API through postman just fine but can seem to get it to work here. My API is through bubble.io. Everything looks like it's set up correctly there since it works with Post Man but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious in the code.

**fetch.js**

```
import { API_URL } from '../secrets';
import { getToken } from './token';


const getHeaders = async () => {
  const token = await getToken();
  const headers = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };

  if (token) {
    headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }

  return headers;
};

export const post = async (destination, body) => {
  const headers = await getHeaders();

  const result = await fetch(`${API_URL}${destination}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  });
  console.log(response.data);

  if (result.ok) {
    return await result.json();
  }
  throw { error: result.status };
};

export const get = async (destination) => {
  const headers = await getHeaders();

  const result = await fetch(`${API_URL}${destination}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers,
  });

  if (result.ok) {
    return await result.json();
  }

  throw { error: result.status };
};
```

**authentication.js**

```
import { post } from './fetch';

export const login = (email, password) => {
  return post('/login', {
    user: { email, password },
  });
};

export const createAccount = (email, password) => {
  return post('/users', {
    user: { email, password },
  });
};
```

**token.js**

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

export const getToken = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@auth_token');
    if (value !== null) {
      return value;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
};

export const setToken = async (token) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@auth_token', token);
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
};
```

**LoginScreen.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { login } from '../../api/authentication';
import EmailForm from '../../forms/EmailForm';

const LoginScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <EmailForm
      buttonText="Log in"
      onSubmit={login}
      onAuthentication={() => navigation.navigate('Menu')}
    >
      <Button
        title="Create account"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('CreateAccount')}
      />
    </EmailForm>
  );
};

export default LoginScreen;
```

Comment: Can you add the error to the post?

Comment: This is what I get in the console: POST https://church1099.com/api/1.1/wf/login 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Sounds like you're not making the request properly. Are you sure the API url in your secrets is the right one? Double check that everything (endpoints, headers, params) is the same as your Postman request.

Comment: I think I'm really lost when it comes to accessing headers, endpoints and certain parts of the API. I've tried reading up on articles but keep coming back at a loss. Thank you for your help!